# iphone redirect shell command

Tags: iphone, shell, command, jailbreak

I am working on an jail broken iphone app that calls a shell command. To read the output I redirect the output of the command to file. That is where my problem lies. When I attempt to do the redirect sh reports that the operation is not permitted.this is the exact output of gdb: `sh: ./tmp/tmp.out: Operation not permitted` Also I call my command using the system() function. thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might instead want to use [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is built for these sorts of things.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge nstask is not apart of the cocoa touch library any other ideas?

Comment: @romejoe It's there (I checked), not documented though

Comment: ok what header or framework file do I have to import in order to access it? also is nstask available in all firmware versions?

Comment: @romejoe I would try copying `NSTask.h` from `Foundation.framework` for Mac. You shouldn't have to link against anything extra. I would imagine it's available on all firmwares, but I can only confirm iOS 4.

Comment: thank you this works after im done testing ill reply with if nstask works on all firmwares